# Programmatic table navigation

Tags: sapui5

I have a sap.m.Table with quite a huge amount of ListItems (rows). When a defined event occurs I would like to navigate to a dedicated ListItem (row). The eventhandler is called and I know the Item I want to navigate to but how can I trigger the navigation?

Had a look at documentation and debugged the source code but haven't found something useful. Did I oversee it?
Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Please add some of your code, that will be easier to understand.

Comment: What code do you want to see here? I have a table with e.g. 500 records and want to programmatically navigate to e.g. record no. 387. I was looking for something like sap.m.Table.navTo(387) or sap.m.Table.navTo(ListItem)

Comment: So you want to scroll down to record 387 on click of a particular record, right?

Comment: No, image the following use case. I have a button in my view. When clicking on it the user can enter a record number (e.g. 387). I then want to move to that item in the list.
_This is just a simplified use case. The real one get's the record number (or ListItem) via a timer_

Answer (score 0):

Try Selecting the Item by id or Item itself

Get all the Items using getItems() and take the item based on index and then select the item using [setSelectedItem(item,true)](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#setSelectedItem)

i have not tried by writing code. try this.

Comment: I already tried that as first solution. Doesn't work. It selects the record but does not move to it. The user still has to scroll down manually.